# JasperReports dynamic input controls

Tags: input, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm currently trying to create a JasperReport report with some special input control behaviour. My needs are:

- four input controls, two of them are dateboxes, the other ones are radio buttons
- depending on radio button choice, one of the databoxes should be visible or not
- so if option 1 is chosen, show both dateboxes; if option 2 is chosen, show only one datebox

I wonder if there's a "clean" solution - didn't find anything.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Print when expression is not relevant for input controls on JasperReports Server.

There is no built-in support for hiding and showing an input control based on the value of a different one. The infrastructure for cascading input controls can certainly be extended to achieve this... but it would not be trivial.

The path I would take is to customize the .jsp page that displays the input control. There is a section in the JasperReports Server Ultimate Guide called "Customizing the Input Controls Form" which would get you started down this path.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your statement confirms my assumption; seems like its the only way by customizing the .jsp page without things getting too complex.

Answer (score 0):

For datebox part, you can use `print when expression` to decide whether certain blocks of the report is visible.

For other "input", if you meant some data you want to display inside the report, you can make some `Parameter` in your report, then set the `Parameter` from user input before you export the report.

Comment: Hey Rangi, thank you for your answer. I've already tried to set printWhen expression - but input controls, unfortunately, doesn't accept this attribute. Basically what i want to achieve is: if option 1 is selected, then the query will use both dates, otherwise only show one datebox and use its value in the query.

Comment: what do you mean by "dosen't accpet this attribute" ? You really need to add more information. What is your application ? How dose user export the report ? What problem you have when you try to use `printWhenExpression` ?

Comment: Well I've got a report deployed on JasperServer, which evaluates data of a specified date range - this range is set by user, either by setting both dateboxes(FromDate-ToDate) OR setting only one datebox(FromSpecifiedDate-today). The user should be able to decide, by radio button, which dateboxes to show. InputControls are related to parameters defined in my report, so it's not possible to set printWhen by <parameter name="myParam" printWhen="..." /> or am I wrong? By setting the attribute I get the error "Attribute 'printWhen' is not allowed to appear in element 'parameter'"