# JasperReports Server: Make the input control depends on the other one

Tags: input, jasper-reports, controls, jasperserver

I'm using *iReport 5.0.0* and *JasperReports Server 5.0.0*.

*And my problem is*: I have 2 input control, the one is Boolean Type and the other is text box, and the value of text box depend on the value of Boolean is "true" or "false. When the user select "true", I want to show "Y" in text box. and when he select "false" I want to show "N" in text box too.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You can look at this post: [JasperReports dynamic input controls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10443938/876298)

Comment: The topic *Cascading Input Controls* of [*JasperReports Server User Guide*](http://community.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/docs/jasperreports-server-user-guide.pdf) can help you

Comment: Sorry for lately reply, because I must test many solution for clear my problem. And I'm already clear. Thank you very much for your reply, Alex K. Your answer is very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the answer

Answer (score 0):

> > Suppose your Input_Controls's IDs are
> >
> > 1. input_boolean
> > 2. input_textarea
>
> For Each input-control there will be parameters inside report, namely
>   `$P{input_boolean}` and `$P{input_textarea}`.
>
> To answer your question, In 'Default Value Expression' of
>   `$P{input_textarea}`  use Ternary Operator expression like this
>
> ```
> ( $P{input_boolean} ? "Y" : "N")
> ```

This will works, like charm.